# Laravel Eloquent Where Created At

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to query my NewsItem table for articles written in a given month / year.

I'm passing the url a GET variable

```
'/news?filter=true&month=January 2017'
```

In my controller I'm catching the variable and trying to run the query on my modal

```
if(Input::get('month')){
   $articles = NewsItem::where(DB::raw('created_at'),function($d){
        Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->format('F Y') = Input::get('month');
   })->get();
};
```

But I get the following error

> FatalErrorException in NewsController.php line 28: Can't use method
>   return value in write context

I'd like to know more about the function element within eloquent, are there any articles that will guide me in the right direction?

Comment: I assume the created_at field of the news_items table is a datetime field?

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to be modified like this

```
if (Input::get('month')) {
    $articles = NewsItem::where('created_at', Carbon::parse(Input::get('month'))->format('F Y'))->get();
};
```

Refer [Laravel Where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) and [Eloquent 101](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8) more information

Answer (score 0):

Assuming created_at is a normal `datetime` field.

If you need all the articles from that month, you can use between combined with some nice Carbon helpers, so there's no need to use a closure in this case.

Example:

```
// Garble or empty inputs will throw an Exception in Carbon
try {
    // this will create a Carbon object or Carbon will throw an exception
    $date = Carbon::parse(request()->input('month'));

    $articles = NewsItem::whereBetween('created_at', [
          $date->startOfMonth()->toDateTimeString(),
          $date->endOfMonth()->toDateTimeString(),
    ])->get();

} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // gracefully handle  Exception
    dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

So using a closure here is not required here.

If you want to see examples on how to use them, see [Laravel query parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping)

---

Some additional examples on closures:

In your case, instead of using between, you could also group the 2 in a closure like this:

```
// Garble or empty inputs will throw an Exception in Carbon
try {
    // this will create a Carbon object or Carbon will throw an exception
    $date = Carbon::parse(request()->input('month'));

    $articles = NewsItem::where('created_at', function($query) use($date) {
        $query
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $date->startOfMonth()->toDateTimeString())
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $date->endOfMonth()->toDateTimeString());
    })->get();

} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // gracefully handle  Exception
    dd($e->getMessage());
}
```